# Sending Commands to a Windowless Command Line process (started from the C# Application)

Tags: c#, command-line

I've got a command line application that starts up and does some work. During that time, it listens to keystrokes (s => show status). It's not the typical command prompt where you press 's' and <ENTER> - it's the type which reacts as soon as the key is pressed the status is shown.

Now I'm trying to "control" that command line application from a fancy GUI application by sending keystrokes. I've tried the more conventional approach of writing to the Process' StandardInput but that doesn't seem to have an effect at all. Also, because the actual process doesn't have a window (it's started with CreateNoWindow=true) I can't try the Win32 API for sending keystrokes to a window.

Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Is the command line application one you wrote (or at least have the source code to)? If so, I'd refactor out the bit that you want to reuse into a separate library which both the GUI and the command-line tool use.

Comment: Did you made sure to Flush the stream when using the Process'StandardInput ?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Heh, if I had the luxury of source code I wouldn't be asking the question :P I'd just change the application to work better. 

Yeah, I did FLUSH the stream by calling the Flush() command. Didn't help.

Comment: Can you create the console application with a hidden window (wShowWindow=SW_HIDE) and then send keystrokes to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I seem to have found an answer to my own question. 
It's a real "kludged together" solution, but it works - and for all the intents and purposes of the application I'm building, it doesn't matter.

So, what I did was use two WinAPI functions called

```
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr WindowHandle, int nCmdShow);
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr WindowHandle);
```

The first one can be used to Show/Hide a window by changing nCmdShow to 1 and 0 respectively. The other one puts the window (determined by WindowHandle) to the front. Combining these two together, I was able to programmaticly bring the console window up front, do a simple SendKeys.Send(); operation and then hide it again.

```
// Use a WIN API command to bring the command line to front
SetForegroundWindow(workerProcess.MainWindowHandle);
// Send a keystore to re-display the STATUS of the worker
SendKeys.Send("s");
// Hide the window again.
ShowWindow(workerProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0);
```

Now, it's a real kludge job, but it gets the job done. One potential pitfall would be if a user is using the computer for something else, and would nail that 1 in a 10000000 moment when the window is active with a 'q' - it would quit the worker program. But the application is intended to be used on dedicated machines that most likely won't even have monitors, keyboards or mice attached to them so it wouldn't be an issue.

Thanks to all who answered, since you did - in one way or another, steer me towards the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Fancy console applications are problematic.

They have a tendency to directly read the keyboard input, instead of going through stdin. They also have a tendency to directly control their console, instead of going through stdout.

AFAIK, there is no way to programmatically control these apps. If you really, *really* need to, I would explore something like [`AutoHotKey`](http://www.autohotkey.com/) controlling the app on a private [desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687098%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (AHK uses a virtual keyboard/mouse driver). I'm not sure how you would read the results off the console, though; it *may* be possible to create an intermediate console app that's started by your program (in the private desktop) and starts the target app. The intermediate app would then [share its console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the target app and use [low-level I/O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to detect changes.

Or you could use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to bend the target app to your will.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I'm able to read from it easily. Only sending input seems to be a problem. I'll check those two things out and see if any of it works. EDIT: Quite strange that sending a keystroke (as if it was typed on a keyboard) isn't as standard as writing to STDIN :)

Comment: There's an arms race, actually. On the one side are the apps that *really* want to read from a *real* keyboard, and on the other side are the apps that *really* want to fake out those apps. `WM_KEYUP`/`WM_KEYDOWN`, `keybd_event`, `SendInput` (`SendKeys`), etc. I once was contracted to write a virtual keyboard driver because there was a program that simply refused to be virtualized. In the arms race, virtualization always wins. :) Until TPM is used. :(

Answer (score 1):

I found an even better way to accomplish the functionality without the theoretical risk of causing problems with simultaneous user input and window-switching.

The trick is to use the WinAPI functions called PostMessage to send up KeyDown (or KeyUp) message to the process which does the same thing. No need to bring the process window to the front and hide it immediately afterwards!

I'm sending the key-down command with key 'S' as the argument:

```
        // 0x0100 - VM_KEYDOWN
        // 0x0101 - VM_KEYUP
        // 0x53 - S-key
        PostMessage(workerProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0x0100, 0x53, 0);
        PostMessage(workerProcess.MainWindowHandle, 0x0101, 0x53, 0);
```

Comment: PostMessage? Where it come from?

Comment: WinAPI functions

Comment: Does it work for hidden cmd application ? i try to send message to visible application and i can without any problem but when target application is hidden it doesn't work in my case

Comment: @Cozdemir It worked in 2011, but I haven't touched that code since, so I am really not sure if the same WinAPI works the same way 11 years later.

Comment: Thank you for response. Actually still works but when i redirectstartdardoutput it doesn't work.