# Submitting input to another windows process

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I send keypresses to a running process object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686865/how-can-i-send-keypresses-to-a-running-process-object)

I have a windows software that has a login form and then automatically does something.
I would like from my c# application to launch it and AUTOMATICALLY fil in the login form with username and password.

Using Process class I was able to launch programmatically the software, so my question is:

When the other process login form is shown it is possible to fill the data automatically from c#?

Comment: It is not very clear here. Can you edit to be more specific? Are the both processes made by you?

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way of doing this is probably to use something like [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) or straight calls to the Win32 API for input. Althought it's still a pretty fragile way of sending data between two programs, relying on Window focus, the UI not changing et
c...

Comment: Nice - hadn't come across the input simulator before.

Comment: @user730712 You missed something there I think... ?

Comment: just to be clear, I have my application, I have another software that when is launched shows a login screeen. From my application is possible to simulate keystroke so to login?

Comment: Indeed. I would recommend the duplicate question mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686865/how-can-i-send-keypresses-to-a-running-process-object (or check out Windows Input Simulator which I linked to).