# How to simulate key presses in C#

Tags: c#, keypress, sendkeys

How would you go about sending key commands or keypresses of particular keys in C#, specifically numbers.

For instance I would like to simulate typing "512" programatically.

Possibly Related: [C# SendKeys.Send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012616/c-sendkeys-send)

Comment: I'm a little lost, how would you keypress an integer without simulation?

Comment: Please explain what "keypressing" an integer variable means.

Comment: Do you already know how to simulate key-pressing chars and what to know how to do it with integers?  Or is simulating key-pressing the real question here?

Comment: Here's an example. The integer is 512, I know I could simulate keypressing it by entering the key 5, then 1, and finally 2. But as I say - it's not constant so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @John black: Is this what you mean: you have a key code, and you want to trigger whatever mechanism exists in a UI you're interacting with corresponding to the keypress for that code?

Comment: @John black - How are you simulating? What with? What do you mean by "simulate keypressing"?

Comment: In that case you need to raise an event on a Visual Object, let's say a text box

Comment: Please reopen the question so I could accept m0sa's answer. It's a real question, I just didn't describe it well.

Comment: I kind of think the SO users were too quick to close this one. You gave the poor guy like 5 minutes to clarify his question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would use [inputsimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) you could just do:

```
   var number = 2011;
   InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(number.ToString());
```

Comment: oh yes, this would do. Thanks!

Comment: +1: This seems like exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept your answer. They closed my question. :(

Comment: Now I did, don't know why it didn't work last time.

Answer (score 1):

An integer variable doesn't have a UI, so can't have a keypress.

Comment: No, there must be a way!

Comment: @John black - If you know how to do this with a boolean, that will show you the way.

Comment: @John black - I suggest you clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Events are for visual objects, not for variables